# Laravel trying to authenticate and failing

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

**Edit: I've realised my original problem was due to my own stupidity but now have a slightly different problem**

Controller creating api key:

```
$apiKey = new ApiKey;

// Make some random strings for the api key / secret 
$key = 'test'; 
$secret = 'test';

$apiKey->api_key = $key;
$apiKey->api_secret = Hash::make($secret);

$apiKey->save();
```

Filter doing authentication:

```
// Set the auth model to use the API keys table
Config::set('auth.model', 'App\Models\ApiKey');

$credentials = array('api_key' => $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'], 'api_secret' => $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']);

// Attempt to authenticate
if (!Auth::attempt($credentials)) {

    return Response::make('Invalid Credentials.', 401);
}
```

Model ApiKey.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Hash;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;

class ApiKey extends \Eloquent implements UserInterface {

    protected $table = 'api_keys';


    protected $fillable = array('name', 'api_key', 'api_secret', 'active', 'allowed_ip');

    public function getAuthIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->getKey();
    }


    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return $this->api_secret;
    }


}
```

My database has a table 'api_keys', and within that table there is a field 'api_key' and 'api_secret'.

Authentication always fails, and I am getting no errors.

**Edit 2**

I have partially solved my issue.

I found that by renaming my database fields from **api_key** and **api_secret** to simply username and password it all works.

I can also change the username field to whatever I like.

But, if I change the password field name, the auth doesn't work. So I think there must be some problem with the mode, particularly this bit:

```
    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return $this->api_secret;
    }
```

Comment: Where does `$string` come from in `$apiKey->api_secret = Hash::make($string);`? Sure this shouldn't be `$secret`?

Comment: It's the way I have copy and pasted it, going to edit now.

Comment: @dopey, Do you have an `ID` primary key in your `api_keys` table ?

Comment: @RecoveringSince2003 yes I do